# How to refresh parent page after closing dialog box which is not a interactive report

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I tried to refresh a region in parent page while closing modal box in apex but the parent page is not interactive report So dynamic action refresh is not working. what can be done in these situations?

i tried dynamic action with dialog closed option but its not working

no codes as its just action

I need to refresh the parent page even having new button as refresh.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this javascript code after closing the dialog

```
apex.event.trigger( "#myRegionStaticID", "apexrefresh" );
```

Comment: could you please provide details how dynamic action should be configured I tried different options but its not working by running this script after dialog closed

Comment: new DA> event dialog closed, selection type region and select your region> true action javscriptcode

Comment: Hi Mohamed,I tried the same way but its not working. I am having shuttle in my parent page. may be thats creating issue in refresh. Do you think is there any possibility to refresh whole page ?
If not is there any way to refresh a page after clicking one button ?

Comment: Could you demonstrate your question on apex.oracle.com and give me the login data